# Error with sockets in delphi

Tags: delphi

Hi I have a problem with the following code:

```
host := 'localhost';
nickname := 'tester';
canal := '#tester';
code := '';

ClientSocket := TClientSocket.Create(nil);
ClientSocket.host := host;
ClientSocket.Port := 6667;
ClientSocket.Open;

if ClientSocket.Socket.Connected = True then
begin
  Writeln('Connected!');
  while (1 = 1) do
  begin
    code := ClientSocket.Socket.Read();
    if not(code = '') then
    begin
      Writeln(code);
    end;
  end;
end
else
begin
  Writeln('Error');
end;
```

the problem is with the line

```
code: = ClientSocket.Socket.Read();
```

gives me the following error

[DCC Error] irc.dpr (35): E2035 Not enough actual parameters

try putting nil as parameter but I get this new error

[DCC Error] irc.dpr (35): E2010 Incompatible types: 'NativeInt' and 'Pointer'

I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are calling this method (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Win.ScktComp.TCustomWinSocket.Read) which receives a `NativeInt` parameter named `Socket`. This method is a `procedure`, has no return value. Clearly you are calling the wrong method.

Comment: I think ClientSocket.Socket.Read is called internally to generate OnRead Event. Have a look at this examples of how to use sockets: http://delphi.about.com/od/networking/l/aa112602a.htm

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Where did you see that parameter type is NativeInt? The documentation says that the method expects TSocket type.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Cjeck that documentation and you will se that the use of NativeInt is for C++ where I belive NativeInt is used for poiters. Delphi implementation does expect TSocket type result.

Comment: @Silver No, that's not what NativeInt is. It seems clear from the message in the Q that NativeInt is what the compiler expects. Ask yourself what TSocket is.

Comment: @user Why did you decide to call Read? What led you there? It's a mistake to do so.

Comment: @user Also, don't test `=true`, just write `if Connected then`. And `while True` is the idiom. And it's `if code <> ''`.

Comment: TClientSocket does not have a Read function. It has an OnRead event. TClientSocket has been deprecated for ages in favor of Indy's socket implementation, so I'm not sure why you would be using it anyway; I believe it's actually no longer being shipped with newer versions of Delphi.

Comment: @Ken It's TCustomWinSocket.Read, which does exist as can be seen by the compiler error

Comment: @David: TCustomWinSocket has a Read function, but it's not listed in the documentation for TClientSocket as a public or published method. If it's not available in the non-custom descendant, it's a very good indication that you're using it wrong. It also doesn't change that it's been deprecated for years now, and that it was deprecated for a reason (it's a crappy socket implementation).

Comment: @Ken I gave a link to the documentation of the function. Clearly it exists. Equally clearly the asker is wrong to call it.

Comment: @David: Yep, having looked at the source you're right about it being there.

Comment: @KenWhite OK. Everyone's agreed that it should not be called from outside the class though!!

Answer (score 3):

`Read()` is used internally to trigger the `OnRead` event.  You should *never* call it directly.

The `TClientSocket.ClientType` property is set to `ctNonBlocking` by default.  That means the socket runs asynchronously, using an internal window to receive notifications of socket activity.  So you have to use the `OnConnect` event to detect a successful connection, the `OnError` event to detect a failed connect, and the `OnRead` events to receive incoming data.  And you need a message loop so those events can be triggered.  For example:

```
// since you are using a Console app, you can use
// a little hack to assign event handlers...

procedure ClientConnected(Self: Pointer; Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  Writeln('Connected!');
end;

procedure ClientDisconnected(Self: Pointer; Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  Writeln('Disconnected!');
  PostQuitMessage(0);
end;

procedure ClientError(Self: Pointer; Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent; var ErrorCode: Integer);
begin
  Writeln('Socket Error! ', ErrorCode);
  if ErrorEvent = eeConnect then
    PostQuitMessage(0);
end;

procedure ClientRead(Self: Pointer; Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  len: Integer;
  Buf: PByte;
begin
  len := Socket.ReceiveLength;
  if len <= 0 then Exit;
  GetMem(Buf, len);
  try
    len := Socket.ReceiveBuf(Buf^, len);
    if len <= 0 then Exit;
    // use data as needed...
  finally
    FreeMem(Buf);
  end;
end;

var
  ClientSocket: TClientSocket;
  M: TMethod;
  Msg: TMsg;
begin
  try
    ClientSocket := TClientSocket.Create(nil);
    try
      ClientSocket.Host := 'localhost';
      ClientSocket.Port := 6667;

      M.Code := @ClientConnected;
      M.Data := ClientSocket;
      ClientSocket.OnConnect := TSocketNotifyEvent(M);

      M.Code := @ClientDisconnected;
      M.Data := ClientSocket;
      ClientSocket.OnDisconnect := TSocketNotifyEvent(M);

      M.Code := @ClientRead;
      M.Data := ClientSocket;
      ClientSocket.OnRead := TSocketNotifyEvent(M);

      M.Code := @ClientError;
      M.Data := ClientSocket;
      ClientSocket.OnError := TSocketErrorEvent(M);

      ClientSocket.Open;

      while GetMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0) do
      begin
        TranslateMessage(msg);
        DispatchMessage(msg);
      end;
    finally
      ClientSocket.Free;
    end;
  except
    Writeln('Error');
  end;
end.
```

To write the kind of loop you attempted, you would have to set the `TClientSocket.ClientType` to `ctBlocking` instead, and then use a `TWinSocketStream` for reading and writing.  For example:

```
var
  ClientSocket: TClientSocket;
  Strm: TWinSocketStream;
  len: Integer;
  Buf: array[0..1023] of Byte;
begin
  try
    ClientSocket := TClientSocket.Create(nil);
    try
      ClientSocket.ClientType := ctBlocking;
      ClientSocket.Host := 'localhost';
      ClientSocket.Port := 6667;

      ClientSocket.Open;
      Writeln('Connected!');

      Strm := TWinSocketStream.Create(ClientSocket.Socket, 5000);
      try
        repeat
          len := Strm.Read(Buf[0], SizeOf(Buf));
          if len <= 0 then Break;
          // use data as needed...
         until False;
      finally
        Strm.Free;
      end;
    finally
      ClientSocket.Free;
    end;
  except
    Writeln('Error');
  end;
end.
```